# Turn off log4j2 startup debug logging

Tags: java, logging, log4j, log4j2

How do I turn off the debug logging that log4j2 spits out when it initialises itself?

These sort of things:

2014-10-22 11:16:45,505 DEBUG Building Plugin[name=filter, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.ThresholdFilter]. Searching for builder factory method...
2014-10-22 11:16:45,505 DEBUG No builder factory method found in class org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.ThresholdFilter. Going to try finding a factory method instead.
2014-10-22 11:16:45,505 DEBUG Still building Plugin[name=filter, class=org.apache.logging.log4j.core.filter.ThresholdFilter]. Searching for factory method...

I'm calling log4j2 from a simple Java application via eclipse. By that I mean:
public static void main(String[] args) { ... }

The loggers portion of the xml config is:

```xml
 <Loggers>
    <Root level="trace"/>
    
    <logger name="audit">
        <appender-ref ref="AUDITOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUGOUT"/>
        
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTINFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTWARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTFATAL"/>
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="org.apache.log4j">
        <appender-ref ref="FILEOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTWARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTFATAL"/>
    </logger>
    
    <logger name="jh.Runner2">
        <appender-ref ref="DEBUGOUT"/>
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
        
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTTRACE"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTDEBUG"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTINFO"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTWARN"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTERROR"/>
        <appender-ref ref="ORACLEOUTFATAL"/>
    </logger>
 </Loggers>
```

Appenders:

```xml
 <Appenders>
    <Console name="STDOUT">
        <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%t] - %m%n"/>
    </Console>
    
    <RollingFile name="FILEOUT" fileName="${log-path}/mainlog2.log" filePattern="${log-path}/mainlog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%t] - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    
    <RollingFile name="DEBUGOUT" fileName="${log-path}/debuglog2.log" filePattern="${log-path}/debuglog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p %C [%t] - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    
    <RollingFile name="AUDITOUT" fileName="${log-path}/audit2.log" filePattern="${log-path}/auditlog-%d{yyyy-MM-dd}.log">
        <ThresholdFilter level="INFO" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        <PatternLayout pattern="%d %p [%t] - %m%n"/>
        <Policies>
            <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy interval="1" modulate="true"/>
        </Policies>
    </RollingFile>
    
    <JDBC name="ORACLEOUTTRACE" tableName="J0T_EVENT">
        <Filters>
            <ThresholdFilter level="DEBUG" onMatch="DENY" onMismatch="NEUTRAL"/>
            <ThresholdFilter level="TRACE" onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="DENY"/>
        </Filters>
        <ConnectionFactory class="com.xxxxxxxxx.db.LoggingDBConnectionFactory" method="getDatabaseConnection" />
        <Column name="EVENT_ID" literal="${nextEventID}"/>
        <Column name="APP_NM" literal="${appName}"/>
        <Column name="CREATE_DT" isEventTimestamp="true"/>
        <Column name="EVENT_TYPE_ID" literal="1"/>
        <Column name="EVENT_TXT" pattern="${eventTxtPattern}" isUnicode="false"/>
    </JDBC>
```

etc.

Comment: can you paste your appenders?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your configuration starts with

```
<Configuration status="debug" ...
```

Change this to

```
<Configuration status="warn" ...
```

and you will only see WARN-level internal log4j messages (which is probably what you want).